# Creating Application_Error handler in Global.asax file getting a Parser Error

Tags: c#, sitecore, global-asax, sitecore7, application-error

I am trying to add the Application_Error method into the Global.asax file, but I am getting a parser error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Parser Error Description: An error
>   occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following specific parse error details and
>   modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The content in the application file is not
>   valid.

I do not understand why it this method is not working. Any help is appreciated thanks!

```
<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.Web.Application" %>

using System.Configuration;

protection void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

  // Get the exception object.
  Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

  // Handle HTTP errors
  if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
  {
    // The Complete Error Handling Example generates
    // some errors using URLs with "NoCatch" in them;
    // ignore these here to simulate what would happen
    // if a global.asax handler were not implemented.
    if (exc.Message.Contains("NoCatch") || exc.Message.Contains("maxUrlLength"))
    return;

   //Redirect HTTP errors to HttpError page
   Server.Transfer("HttpErrorPage.aspx");
 }

 // For other kinds of errors give the user some information
 // but stay on the default page
 Response.Write("<h2>Global Page Error</h2>\n");
 Response.Write(
     "<p>" + exc.Message + "</p>\n");
 Response.Write("Return to the <a href='Default.aspx'>" +
  "Default Page</a>\n");

  // Log the exception and notify system operators
  ExceptionUtility.LogException(exc, "DefaultPage");
  ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(exc);

  // Clear the error from the server
  Server.ClearError();
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/24395wz3.aspx

Comment: I am using the following links for code examples of what I am trying to implement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx

Comment: Change `protection void Application_Error` to `protected void Application_Error`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should add the code in the .cs file.

Moreover protection is not accepted. Your code should be like this:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
  //DoSomething();
}
```